# /var/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

1) I am running a docker container with following cmd :

`$ docker run --name=xyz -d -e CONTAINER_NAME=xyz -e SSH_PORT=22 -e NWMODE=HOST -e XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0 --net=host -v /mnt:/mnt -v /dev:/dev -v /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts -v /:/hostroot/ -v /etc/hostname:/etc/host_hostname -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged=true cf3681e04bfb`

2) Inside the container, i have a.py where i create a docker client as shown below :

```
$ cat a.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from docker import Client as DC
dc = DC('unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='auto')
```

3) Running a.py gives following error :

`$ ./a.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 5, in <module>
    dc = DC('unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='auto')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 99, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 124, in _retrieve_server_version
    'Error while fetching server API version: {0}'.format(e)
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))`

4) i have a docker daemon running with unix domain socket in listening mode :

`$ netstat --listen | grep docker
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11146    /var/run/docker.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17471    /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17648    /run/docker/libnetwork/02833519b1ad75ad062f6443ab5c10e5d9c783c22beb98d8b8b41b2ee082cfcd.sock`

5) Inside the container, i get :

`$ curl --verbose --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json
*   Trying /var/run/docker.sock...
* Immediate connect fail for /var/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`

6) If i exit from the container and run same curl cmd on the host machine, it works fine :

`$ exit    //coming out from the container
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json
[{"Id":"3973df106fcfae0d1f5b4be23b6e5f265421aa932053433f5e9e7bc9574d753a","Names"......multiple key-value pairs here...]`

can anyone let me know what may be the probable cause of error in steps 3/5 above. What else can be tried to debug it further. thanks.

Comment: I guess your problem is with: `'No such file or directory'`, and don't you need a `http://` not `http:/` ?

Comment: You could point it at `/hostroot/var/run/docker.sock`.  Or add a `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` option.  Or just run the process on the host; you’re bypassing basically every single bit of isolation Docker offers.

Comment: @Edwin : the same curl command outside the docker works fine as shown above. so http:/ should be fine. Yes how to debug this problem of `No such file or directory`

Comment: @DavidMaze : i am already using `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` as seen in the point 1 above. is there anything else that can be tried ?

Answer (score 0):

It will work only on nodes. If you want it to work inside container make sure you mount /var/run using volumes hostPath method.

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://docker/containers/json
```